# Table view not displaying firebase data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I have a bunch of images and those images have "like" buttons. When the logged in user likes any of the images, the ID of the image is sent to Firebase. In the view controller in which I want to retrieve the "like" message, on `viewDidLoad()`, I get all the liked photos ID and store them into the variable ID.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
  FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Likes").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in


            self.ID = snapshot.key
            print(self.ID!)
        })


        loadData()
    }
```

Then in the loadData function, I try to get all the post with the ID in the Likes node.

```
func loadData(){

    if let ID = self.ID {
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("books").child(ID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

            if let postsDictionary = snapshot .value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                for post in postsDictionary {
                    self.posts.add(post.value)
                }
                self.SoldTableView.reloadData()

            }})
    }
```

But nothing is being displayed in the table view and im not getting an error.

This is what my JSON looks like:
[image]

Comment: "I get all the liked photos ID and store them into the variable ID. " - How do you store **multiple** IDs into the single variable ID? It isn't very clear, from the question, what you are trying to accomplish with that.

Comment: i am trying to look through the books node for those IDs and display their content @NicolasMiari

Comment: Instead of `self.ID`, shouldn't you be using an **array**?

Comment: I set `var ID = [String]()` but in the `loadData()` function I get an error on  `if let ID = self.ID {` saying initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not [String] @NicolasMiari

Comment: - Are you getting the value for postsDictionary? (maybe try print it to check) - you really want to reloadData() when you're sure all data is added

Comment: also I noticed you are calling loadData() outside the FIR block, as its asynchronous your loadData may get called before FIR gets your data